# Extending Yii2 Webvimark user extension

Tags: php, yii2, webvimark

I'm utilizing the Yii2 basic template, with the Webvimark User Management extension.  I have added a couple of additional fields to the "user" table, and would like to expose them to the application in a way that won't get stepped on when I update the application.

For example, if a user was a customer they would have an associated record in the "customer" model, and within root\vendor\webvimark\user-management-module\models\User.php I would add:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['customer_id' => 'customer_id']);
}
```

There are a couple of other modifications I have made, such as adding the "customer" column to the root\vendor\webvimark\user-management-module\views\user\view.php, and selection to the _form.php form, etc.

Ideally, I assume, these types of modifications should be housed somewhere outside of the ..\vendor folder, because they will get overridden when I update the webvimark extension.

I'm a little green on Yii2, frameworks, and namespaces.  What I'd like to do, is any files within the vendor folder that need modified would be housed in \components\user (or whatever) and extend the appropriate file withing the vendor folder.  Is this easily possible?  What's the "best" way to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should never update code in the vendor folder. You need create a new model in your app and extend `webvimark\user-management-module\models\User`

Comment: @KevinP I definitely understand that I didn't do it correctly. Was hoping there was an easy way I could extend the vendor class with my own and update the underlying forms without having to rebuild the extensions existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I went a completely different route.  I forked the webvimark user management module into my own github, and made my changes there.

Then I updated my composer.json file for the main application to point to my fork:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/pascoea/user-management"
    }
  ],
```

and under the "require" header changed the user-management-module to use the dev-master branch in my fork:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "webvimark/module-user-management": "dev-master",
    ...
},
```

After running "Composer update" I was in business.

More info here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#publishing-to-a-vcs